# NaN in tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, kotlin, keras

i created a model with Keras and have

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape=(size,size,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax',name='predictions')
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

my predict in Python:

```
print(model.predict(x))
```

return:

```
[[1. 0.]]
```

and convert model to tflite:

```
# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

And when I implement this in kotlin to app:

```
val resizeBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, true)
        val model = com.example.iscanner.ml.Model.newInstance(context)
        val theBuffer = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resizeBitmap)
        val byteBuffer = theBuffer.buffer
        val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 150, 150, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)
        val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
        val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
        val tab = outputFeature0.floatArray
        model.close()
        Log.d("Tab_test[0]", " "+ tab[0])
        Log.d("Tab_test[1]", " "+ tab[1])
```

Have this:

```
D/Tab_test[0]:  NaN
D/Tab_test[1]:  NaN
```

Anyone know where the problem could be?
And how do I fix it?

It implements a different network and the type is DataType.UINT8 and here is DataType.FLOAT32
Could it be because of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its help,
everything works correctly

```
val resizeBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, true)
        val model = com.example.iscanner.ml.Model.newInstance(context)

        val bytebuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*150*150*3)
        bytebuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        val intValues  = IntArray(150*150)
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues,0,resizeBitmap.width,0,0,resizeBitmap.width,resizeBitmap.height)
        var pixel = 0
        for( i in 0 .. 149){
            for(j in 0..149){
                val tmpVal = intValues[pixel++]
                bytebuffer.putFloat(((tmpVal shr 16) and  0xFF)*(1.0f/1))
                bytebuffer.putFloat(((tmpVal shr 8) and  0xFF)*(1.0f/1))
                bytebuffer.putFloat((tmpVal and  0xFF)*(1.0f/1))
            }
        }
        val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 150, 150, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(bytebuffer)
        val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
        val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
        val tab = outputFeature0.floatArray
        model.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

NaN stands for not a number

NaN occurs when math operation is not valid like a division by zero

check out this [isnan](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

Comment: But, this is the result of the model :/ 
And it implements it in Kotlin, it should return 0-1 digits

Comment: maybe try Pickle to save your model.
usually you dont have to think to much about dataType in python, but a uint8 and a float32 is very different ... so making sure you work with the same dataType could be a good start toward debugging.

its not quite clear where you get your NaN ?
is yet when you try to predict with the converted model ?

the output vector is all NAN ? or just a few one ?
If its all NaN than dataType is very good start to dig in ... if its just a few than i would suspect a conversion model error

Comment: They're all NaN, so it's probably a DataType.UNIT8 / FLOAT32 problem
The problem is in Kotlin in running the tflite model, not in Python